# What $handle does Wordpress use for a theme's implicit style.css?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

Assume that we have a theme named `parent_theme`. This theme's `style.css` will be automatically included in the styles we deliver to the client.

My question is - when Wordpress "includes" `style.css`, what `$handle` does it use? By `$handle`, I mean within the context of [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/). I started digging through the code to find the answer, but thought I'd ask here first.

I would assume it's the "stylesheet name", aka the name of the directory that contains the theme. I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work.

---

(Also, if you're curious, I'm asking because I have a `child_theme` based on `parent_theme`, and I need to make sure that all of the dependencies are correctly sorted out regardless of whether `parent_theme` is in use or `child_theme` is in use. I can get *very close* to what I want by simply leaving the `$deps` parameter empty in my `wp_enqueue_style()` calls in `parent_theme`, but it would be awesome to have a little more fine-tuning control).

Comment: Also, it's possible that the ultimate answer is, "you're crazy; you shouldn't ever need to do that". If that's the case, feel free to say so! Although if there is, indeed, a `$handle` used for the default `style.css`, I'd love to know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Themes' `style.css` files are not enqueued for printing automatically (see [the developer handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#stylesheets)) - instead this responsibility is left to the theme developer. As such, you'll need to delve into the parent theme's source files to determine the appropriate handle. That said, developers sometimes default to using `'theme'` or `'style'` handles.

Note that the developer may have opted to load the stylesheet directly in their header file, or a function hooked to `wp_print_styles`/`wp_head` by explicitly printing an appropriate `<link>` element, in which case there will be no handle and you may need to replicate the corresponding function/template in your child theme or alter action priorities in order modify the loading process.

Further, if your child theme's files prevent the parent theme's `style.css` from enquing in the first place, you'll need to manually register or enqueue the parent theme's `style.css` if you wish to use it as a dependency. `get_template_directory_uri()` is useful for this task:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

Comment: Thank you! Your comments are spot on. Furthermore, they led me on a wild Google-chase to [this SO answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14659/10388) about the tendency for themes to include `style.css` via a `<link>` element. Turns out that is *exactly* what my base theme is doing. Seems a little inconsistent to use a combination of `<link>` as well as `wp_enqueue_style()`, but that's exactly what's going on. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I'm familiar with such goose chases :P - sadly stylesheet enquing lacks standardization across the board. WordPress auto-loads locale and text-direction specific stylesheets from a theme's directory, for instance, but for whatever reason they're not enqueued. Maybe one day ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Blech. As I'm diving in more, I'm finding that this theme mixes equal parts of `<link>` CSS and `wp_enqueue_style()` CSS. I don't see any big advantage to using `<link>`. It just seems to complicate things; am I missing something obvious?

Comment: BTW, I thought I'd make this [an actual question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/281205/10388) - feel free to chime in for even more fake internet points! :)