# Advantages of using <link> instead of wp_enqueue_style()?

Tags: theme-development, themes, wp-enqueue-style

I'm working on a child theme for a base theme that mixes equal parts of `<link>` CSS and `wp_enqueue_style()` CSS. This base theme has me thinking - I don't see any advantages to using `<link>`, other than that it *may* it's a simpler solution for very simple themes. (for example, using `<link>` can be done without a `functions.php` file)

As far as I can tell, `<link>` is less flexible than `wp_enqueue_style()`, and using a combination of `<link>` and `wp_enqueue_style()` just makes things downright convoluted.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Note: I'm aware of the questions about advantages of `wp_enqueue_style()` over `<link>`, but as you can see, this question is a little different than that. Thanks for stopping by!

Comment: Also, I discovered another potential niche/advantage: inclusion of CSS via conditional comments (e.g. `<!--[if lt IE 9]><link ... /><![endif]-->`)

Comment: you are trying to compare an html elelement to an API. I am not sure how exactly this can be compared at all.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you must need a `functions.php` to create a theme whether it's a parent theme or child theme. Now if you are gonna need a `functions.php` must then why don't you also use it for enqueuing styles and scripts ! Besides when it is the best practice.

Now if your base theme or parent theme uses `<link>` or combination of `<link>` and `wp_enqueue_style()` then they are doing it wrong. Or they are not aware of or don't care of anything in future can happen. As I already said this a very bad practice and it can be a pain in future if you are gonna maintain the theme for a long time. Also it's not child theme friendly. For your case I think this can be such a pain to create a child theme form this kinda parent theme.

> **And for your IE related comment [please have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564142/wordpress-enqueue-scripts-for-only-if-lt-ie-9).**

Hope this will help.